# php - wrap post elements in <li> tags

Tags: php, wordpress, image, element, html-lists

I'm currently using a system for my portfolio where i add three images per project, which schould be inside an ul.

This works fine, but i need those img tags to be wrapped within li tags, and i have no clue how i should do this.

Take this:

```
<img src="img1.jpg"/>
<img src="img2.jpg"/>
<img src="img3.jpg"/>
```

Make this:

```
<li><img src="img1.jpg"/></li>
<li><img src="img2.jpg"/></li>
<li><img src="img3.jpg"/></li>
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Sorry, here's more info for you guys:

I'm using Wordpress 3 as cms with custom post types.
The output is done via wp's "the_content()", where i put my images.

I know i could use wp's html editor to wrap li tags around manually,
the problem is that i wont be maintaining the site, so i want to make it easer for my coworkers.

This is why its outputting the img tags in a row, and i need to wrap those li tags around them.
I've read something about "preg_replace", but i cant seem to get it working.

EDIT:
I've found the solution, sometimes the easiest way is the best:

```
$thecontent = get_the_content();
$thecontent_format = '<li>'.str_replace(array("\r","\n\n","\n"),array('',"\n","</li>\n<li>"),trim($thecontent,"\n\r")).'</li>';
```

wraps every img element with a li, and then

```
echo $thecontent_format;
```

Anyways, thanks for you participation!

Comment: do you generate this html code in php?

Comment: Is this the entirety of the HTML to process?

Comment: ??? We need more information. What system are you using. The tag is marked PHP, but you could be using *anything* to render those images -- you could even have a sub-process which opens up a Java call to Jython through Closure which returns a compressed unicode string which is translated by Perl into compiled C++ objects and returned to PHP as a base-64 encoded byte-array. (I'm not saying you are, or even that that would be a good idea (though it might be fun if you can be ridiculous), but it is *possible*) (Did I miss anything?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to sound stupid or anything but if your trying to do this with PHP I am assuming that PHP is also creating the img tags for display.... in that case all you have to do is:

```
echo "<li>";
```

image tag generating code goes here

and than close it off with:

```
echo "</li>";
```

do this for every image tag that being created...

Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Thanks YonoRan, but this wont work so easily.
P.S.: I've updated my original post.

Comment: yeah... I thought the answer was WAY to simple.... but the question was a bit lacking...